# Marketing Email - HttpGet Ampscript with XML Response

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, httpresponse

I'm trying to configure an email in Marketing Cloud with the ampscript function HttpGet in order to retrieve a coupon from an external system. 
I've seen that the [HttpGet](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/httpget/) could return these values

- 0 indicates status is OK
- -1 indicates missing URL
- -2 indicates    HTTP request error
- -3 indicates empty content - the function completed successfully but returned no content

How can i manage errors e.g. time-out of this external system? At the same time the system gives me a XML response, i would like to manage fallbacks if there are syntax code error; how can i validate XML response using Ampscript adding a fallback? Because i implemented the function BuildRowSetFromXML, but i didn't see anything used to handle this.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd need to encapsulate your AMPScript in an SSJS Try/Catch block to handle errors from AMPScript...

```
<script runat=server>
try {
</script>

%%[
  SET @try = "Ampscript to try - may raise an error"
]%%

<script runat=server>
}
catch(err) {
</script>

%%[
  SET @catch = "Ampscript to execute - try raised error"
]%%

<script runat=server>
} 
finally {
</script>

%%[
  SET @finally = "Ampscript to run irrespective of outcome of try"
]%%

<script runat=server>
}
</script>
```

A word of caution would be to not consider doing any of this, including your HttpGet from a mass send. HttpGets are slow and mixing AMPScript and SSJS is slow. I would reserve this type of thing for triggered sends where the email taking a few seconds longer to deploy to the customer isn't an issue. One million subscribers' emails each taking a few seconds longer each to deploy is a problem.